# PHP mysqli_query runs twice

Tags: php, mysql

I am working at a large web application project.
Our application sends a real product(food and books). So if the bugs occur then it get a large loss.

But yesterday, at least 250 orders insert twice in our database so it sends two same products to customers.

I don't know why query runs twice, just twice.

I searched on google, stack overflow but many answers say check your code, check your mysql query...
 Our service has been running for 1 years with a same code. It's the first time the bug occer.

What's the problem??

summary::my php code runs mysqli_query one time(as same as log) but it runs twice.

my PK is Auto Increment.. (is this the reason of bug????)

please help

Comment: this happens sometimes under the poor  internet connection on client side. Try adding code to prevent two same request done in short interval. Also add some of your code here, so we can help you to improve your current system

Comment: If you want a really quick fix, add a column 'guid' that has a unique index on it. Then just generate a random `SHA512` hash and insert the order into the database. This means that even if two queries go through, it will only save one into the database. I wouldn't suggest doing this permanently, but this is if you need a fix until you can figure out the issue, do this.

Comment: @FrozenFire thank you for your comment. But it's not that problem.. We got a data from excel, and we do that thing on the server. My program read excel data and insert in order. In our database, if the problem like your answer it may A, B, C, D, A, B, C, D. but in my case A, A, B,B, C, C, D,D

Comment: @FrozenFire And also it's the first time the bug occured..

Comment: @Matt ah.. if I use your answer. any problems with performace?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an AUTO_INCREMENT you could try checking if the I'd doesn't exist, if it doesn't you run your code.
Perhaps it is not the best way but it is a solution while you check why your bug happened